# ListContainer.js is not a js file in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In WebStorm 2016.2, MacBook Pro with OSX 10.11.3.

My `./MyProject/List` folder content:

[image]

I created `ListContainer.js` by the step:

- Mouse point hover `List` folder
- `New`
- `JavaScript File`
- type `ListContainer.js`
- click "OK"

Pay attention to the file icon: it's not normal js file icon.

Inside the file (when editing it) WebStorm does not provide any syntax hightlighting of React code.

When investigating I found out that such confusing behaviour only happens with file(s) named `ListContainer.js` (upper case  L and C).

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872024/webstorm-not-recognising-javascript-file/26888078#26888078

Comment: You should not have typed `.js` when creating new file *using specific template*. In any case -- use solution that @anstarovoyt pointed to -- find unwanted pattern that associates this file with Text Files and remove it -- it will be treated as JavaScript File again.